# How to call geth mining through java code manually ?

Tags: mining, web3j

I am using web3j and Geth and created a private network. However, I want to do the mining manually whenever required, since don't want to jam the server when I am in the development phase. For that, I found JsonRpc2_0Geth update in web3j and used it. However, mining does not start. Please help me where I am going wrong.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>geth</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, i called the Geth aPI through my java file as follows:

```
static public Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("<geth ip>:<port>"));
static public JsonRpc2_0Geth geth = new JsonRpc2_0Geth(new HttpService("<geth ip>:<port>"));
geth.minerStart(1000);
```

Comment: geth.minerStart(1000); asks miner to use 1000 threads, you can try following troubleshooting. 1. Try 1 thread geth.minetStart(1) and try start mining from console. Do any of these work ?

Comment: mining from geth console works. Not from the java file though. How can i troubleshoot for java ?

Comment: Does it work with geth.minerStart(1)

Comment: And what is the full command line that is used to start geth ?

Comment: No,  geth.minerStart(1) did not work for me. The way i used it is mentioned in my original draft.                                                                                                                                       The way i started geth node is :                                                                   
 `geth --port 3000 --networkid 1996 --nodiscover --datadir=./datadir --maxpeers=0 --rpc --rpcport 8585 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner, admin, txpool" console`

Comment: Does it work with `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` ?

Comment: --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" works for me.  Just to update you: `geth --port 3000 --networkid 1996 --nodiscover --datadir=./datadir --maxpeers=0 --rpc --rpcport 8585 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner, admin, txpool" console`  works on mymachine. also mining works using this geth console. What doesnt work for me mining from java file using web3j . <please check my original draft>

Comment: Can someone please help me?  I am stuck . Else, is  there any other way to start geth mining through java ?

Comment: Is Java program running on the same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Posting to RPC URL is a way to start mining from any language

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":[1],"id":74}
```

I.e. post this data to RPC URL.

Command line example is :

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":[4],"id":74}' localhost:8545
```

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs

This page has example of sending a POST request from Java.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: I am trying this solution. Thanks for the response . Will update you soon.